# In a Rails helper method, is it possible to specify a column name as a helper method variable and then use it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I want to create a helper method that can turn the results of a Rails find into a sentence, where I specify the the results, and the column to use for making the sentence. For example:

```
  def items_to_sentence(items, label_column)
    items.map { |u| u.(label_column) }.to_sentence
  end
```

I'm just not sure how to tell Rails to use my specified column.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `items` contains ActiveRecord objects (or any other objects that have accessor methods that match up with your column names), then you could use [`send`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000999):

```
def items_to_sentence(items, label_column)
  items.map { |u| u.send(label_column) }.to_sentence
end
```

Or equivalently:

```
def items_to_sentence(items, label_column)
  items.map(&(label_column.to_sym)).to_sentence
end
```

Or, if that's too noisy:

```
def items_to_sentence(items, label_column)
  sym = label_column.to_sym
  items.map(&sym).to_sentence
end
```